# How to delete substrings given in an array from entries in a list in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of strings to delete:

```
string[] delStrings = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"}
```

Then I have a List of directories:

```
List<string> dirs = new(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path));
```

So far I have:

```
var matches = from dir in dirs
              where delStrings.Any( str => dir.Contains(str) )
              select dir;

foreach ( string oldName in matches ) {
  // ==> how to delete any delString <==
  // something such
  // string subString = delStrings.Any( str => oldName.Contains(str) )

  string newName = oldName.Replace( subString, string.Empty );
  System.IO.Directory.Move( oldName, newName );
}
```

Which gets all directory names that contain a delString.
Now I want to replace any delString in every entry of dirs by
string.Empty.

How is this accomplished most efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do what you're asking like this:

```
foreach (string oldName in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).ToList())
{
    string newName = delStrings.Aggregate(oldName, (a, x) => a.Replace(x, String.Empty));
    if (newName != oldName)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.Move(oldName, newName);
    }
}
```

That simply tries to replace each of the `delStrings` in the `oldName`, one at a time. If the string doesn't exist then you don't change the old string.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the job for me.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do matches. Instead do two loops:

```
foreach (var dir in dirs)
{
   foreach (var match in delStrings.ToList())
   {
       if (match == dir)
       {
         dir = string.empty;
         break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP was asking for.